# "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey" in my Flutter App

Tags: flutter

I hope someone can help me.
I have some stateful widgets in my Flutter app as they are different dashboards.

```
GlobalKey projectStreamGlobalKey = GlobalKey<_ProjectStreamState>();
var projectStreamWidget = ProjectStream(projectStreamGlobalKey);

class ProjectStream extends StatefulWidget {
  ProjectStream(Key key) : super(key: key) {
  }

  @override
  State<ProjectStream> createState() => _ProjectStreamState();
}

class _ProjectStreamState extends State<ProjectStream> {

  _ProjectStreamState(){
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(...);
}
}
```

When I switch to the respective screen via the bottom menu I do it with the following code:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => projectStreamWidget));
```

After some time, suddenly the messages "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey" in my Flutter App" are displayed constantly (almost every second). Partly from screens on which I am not active at all.
An example:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

The key [LabeledGlobalKey<_ProjectStreamState>#260bd] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were:
- Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, tooltip: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#83764 NEEDS-PAINT)
- Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, tooltip: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#c5788 NEEDS-PAINT)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

Do I understand something wrong, or am I not allowed to work with stateful widgets like this? Thanks in advance for your messages.

Tried using Stateless Widgets, but the memory is getting really big because of the dashboard data.

Comment: Could you share an example of one of the other widgets that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this line inside your _ProjectStreamState class instead of outside :

```
GlobalKey projectStreamGlobalKey = GlobalKey<_ProjectStreamState>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I rebuilt my app and the error is gone. Unfortunately, this gives me another error (should it be an error). When I navigate to the widget multiple times then in the background I have the widget multiple times in the widget tree. Can this cause performance issues?

Comment: It will not affect your app , it's just a warning .

Comment: So its no problem if the same widget is multiple times in the widget tree? My first solution was to keep the key global and thus always call the same widget with this key. But if the key is directly in the state then it seems that the widget is always recreated in the widget tree (and then i have the widget multiple times in the widget tree, as i can see in the flutter devtools).

Comment: True , but is better to initialize the Global Key inside the class so if it rebuilds , it will rebuild an other key , so it will not show the warning again .

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you clean up the old widgets in the tree or does Flutter do that itself at some point?

Comment: When I was facing this issue , Flutter was cleaning it when I "Hot Restart" the app .